# Can I add a List<> of unknown type to a class?

Tags: c#

I have a class defined as:

```
public class ReportObjectInformation
{
    public string tableName { get; set; }
    public int progressBarValue { get; set; }
    public int rowCount { get; set; }
    public bool canConnect { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string summaryFile { get; set; }
    public string reportFile { get; set; }
    public string errorFile { get; set; }
}
```

I currently have seven different lists of objects in my code.  Is there a way I can do something like:

```
public class ReportObjectInformation
{
    public string tableName { get; set; }
    public int progressBarValue { get; set; }
    public int rowCount { get; set; }
    public bool canConnect { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string summaryFile { get; set; }
    public string reportFile { get; set; }
    public string errorFile { get; set; }
    public List<> listOne { get; set; }  // add this
    public List<> listTwo { get; set; }  // add this
}
```

And then in my code set the list to be one of my seven predefined types of lists?

One of my other lists is made up of this class:

```
class parameters
{
    public string firstName{ get; set; }
    public string lastName{ get; set; }
    public string address{ get; set; }
    public string city{ get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string country{ get; set; }
    public string active_flag { get; set; }
}
```

which I create in my code as:

```
List<parameters> parm_list = new List<parameters>();
```

The parm_list is populated with data.  Now I want to add that list to this other object I'm creating.  At other times in my code I'll want to set the list to one of the my other types but for now how would I do this?  Is this even possible?

```
ReportObjectInformation reportObject = new ReportObjectInformation();
reportObject.tableName = "UserInformation";
reportObject.listOne = parm_list;
reportObject.listTwo = someother_list;
```

Comment: I think you might want to make `ReportObjectInformation` generic, but it's not clear what you are trying to achieve here.  What are the "7 types of lists"?

Comment: The 7 lists are just lists of 7 different classes.  Think of it like List<string>, List<int>, List<char> etc... but instead of those basics (int, string, char) I'm using the classes that I have created.

Comment: @JohnJenkins Are those 7 classes related in any way?  Do you want the list to only contain objects of one type for one instance of `ReportObjectInformation` or a mixture of all 7?

Comment: The 7 classes are completely unrelated.  I want to create a ReportObjectInformation and use a list of class1.  Then create another ReportObjectInformation and use a list of class2, and so on.

Comment: @juharr, okay now that I've had some time to think about this I better understand.  I do need the lists to be capable of handling any one of those seven classes.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you need to mix the classes in the list or just swap out different list of each type.  If the former then you are reduced to either creating a common interface for the classes, or using `List<object>`.  If the latter then you could use `IList` as in Alegnem's answer.  The best bet is to figure out a common interface for the classes if possible.

Comment: @juharr, I need the latter.  I have a work around for it, it's not elegant, but it works.  Will the IList really be inefficient?  How much of a hit would I take on that?

Comment: @JohJenkins It depends on how you use it.  The code could get messy.  I'd suggest finding a way to avoid this requirement if possible.

Comment: @juharr, thanks for your help.  I appreciate  your input.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee that a particular instance of `ReportObjectInformation` will work with a given type of List you can do this:

```
public class ReportObjectInformation<TOne, TTwo>
{
    public string tableName { get; set; }
    public int progressBarValue { get; set; }
    public int rowCount { get; set; }
    public bool canConnect { get; set; }
    public int index { get; set; }
    public string summaryFile { get; set; }
    public string reportFile { get; set; }
    public string errorFile { get; set; }
    public List<TOne> listOne { get; set; }  
    public List<TTwo> listTwo { get; set; }  
}
```

Which lets you specify which types you want the ReportObjectInformation object lists to use.

Answer (score 1):

You could make `ReportObjectInformation` generic

```
public class ReportObjectInformation<TOne, TTwo>
{
    public List<TOne> listOne { get; set; }  // add this
    public List<TTwo> listTwo { get; set; }  // add this
}
```

Then create an instance like this

```
var reportInfo = new ReportObjectInformation<parameters, otherClass>();
reportInfo.listOne = new List<parameters>();
reportInfo.listTwo = new List<otherClass>();
```

Of course this means that each instance can not switch to hold a list of one of the other types.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you want to assign of lists of different types to the object during runtime, you'll be left with no type checking. Can be implemented like:

```
public class ContainingClass
{
    public IList SomeList { get; set; }
}
```

then you can do

```
var c = new ContainingClass();
c.SomeList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
c.SomeList = new List<string> { "abc", "def" };

foreach (var member in c.SomeList)
    Console.WriteLine(member);
```

But you should only do this as a last resort, generally prefer using generics or clean design, because this is:

1. Slow - you'll have to cast a lot since `IList` works with `object`
2. Unsafe - who knows what list is there at a given time? Not to mention you'll be left without compile-time type checks (those are very powerful to have, try not to lose them).

Generally consider this a no-go unless you really really really have no choice (e.g. legacy code compatibility).